# Color variation for trees in Unity Editor

Tags: unity, terrain

I am reading a book on Unity. I met a topic about color variation option for the trees in the terrain. I went to try it on my own in the editor, but was disappointed when did not find it. So my question is where can I find the color variation option or what can I use instead?

Here is screenshot from the book and from my editor.

[image]

[image]

I am using 5.6.1f1 Personal (64bit) right now. [Here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1130550/missing-tree-place-color-variation-option.html) is what I found on an issue so far.

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TreeInstance.html and the color property in that link. I'm not exactly experienced with the Terrain feature of Unity, so, all I can offer is some Google-fu ;)

Comment: @JohnHamilton, thank you for the help. There is a drawback in using TreeInstance since you will have to create some scripts and tweak them. It will take relatively a lot of time. It would be more convenient, efficient and faster just to use an editor for the purpose.

Comment: @JohnHamilton, are you using telegram?